# Global Variables having the wrong value associated with them

Tags: c, colors, printf, global-variables, stdio

I made this header file that is supposed to make colours and formatting with printf easier for me, but somehow all the parameters for formatting are from what I can tell active(=1) by default, in spite of me having defined them to be off(=0) by default. Changing them in a .c file to being off doesn't change anything as well

```
#include <stdio.h>

//parameters
short print_bold = 0;//1
short print_LessVisible = 0; //2
short print_cursive = 0;//3
short print_underline = 0;//4
short print_blinking = 0;//5
short print_SwapBackground = 0; //7
short print_SameBackground = 0;//8
short print_crossed = 0;//9
short print_LineOver = 0; //53
short print_HighIntensity = 0;

void text_color(unsigned short color){;
  short print_mode_1 = (print_bold = 1);
  short print_mode_2 = 2 * (print_LessVisible = 1);
  short print_mode_3 = 3 * (print_cursive = 1);
  short print_mode_4 = 4 * (print_underline = 1);
  short print_mode_5 = 5 * (print_blinking = 1);
  //print_mode_6 = print_mode_5
  short print_mode_7 = 7 * (print_SwapBackground = 1);
  short print_mode_8 = 8 * (print_SameBackground = 1);
  short print_mode_9 = 9 * (print_crossed = 1);
  short print_mode_53 = 53 * (print_LineOver = 1);


  int color_value = 30 + color * (color < 8) + 60 * (print_HighIntensity = 1);

  printf("\e[%d;%d;%d;%d;%d;%d;%d;%d;%d;%dm",print_mode_1,print_mode_2,print_mode_3,print_mode_4,print_mode_5,print_mode_7,print_mode_8,print_mode_9,print_mode_53,color_value);
}

void background_color(unsigned short color){
  int color_value = 40 + color * (color < 8) + 60 * (print_HighIntensity = 1);
  printf("\e[%dm",color_value);
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to with assignment in initialializations? For example `short print_mode_1 = (print_bold = 1);`. That is not typical way to do things, and is most likely your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing comparison operator `==` with assignment operator `=`. After you assign `print_bold = 1` it has to be `1`, not `0`.

```
 printf("%d\n", print_bold); // 0
 short print_mode_1 = (print_bold = 1);
 //                             ^^^ - assignment
 //                ^^^ - assignment
 printf("%d\n", print_bold); // 1
```

The result of assignment is what was assigned. `print_mode_1 = (print_bold = 1);` is equal to: `print_bold = 1; print_mode_1 = 1`.

Mixing `=` with `==` is a very very common mistake that happens all the time. Change `=` to `==` if you want to compare, not assign.

Comment: I was trying to do branchless programming, but I didn't realize, that that was only possible with < or > statements and not with =

Comment: Great so do `print_mode_1 = print_bold == 1;`

Comment: @Maximilian: It is possible to write an equality comparison in C without a branch statement. You just use `==`, not `=`. (This just means there is no explicit branch in the source code. It does not mean the compiler will not implement the comparison using a branch instruction.)

Answer (score 0):

While initializing the print_mode variables and color_values I used = as if it was an operator like < or >. I changed `print_mode_x = x * (print_parameter = 1)` to `print_mode_x = x * (print_parameter == 0)` . The reason I used branchless programming was that it allowed me to write less lines of code(and it's actually faster as well).